When to transplant my indoor peach tree outside
I found a peach pit sprouting in my compost earlier this spring. I potted it and have had it growing outside all summer. My plan was to winter it in doors until spring. I don't know if it will survive outside. What should I do for a microclimate come spring to ensure it's survival?

Give it a tight-mesh (1/8" - 3mm opening) wire cage to protect it from rodents (and deer) and plant it now.
The tree fully expects to experience winter. "Sheltering" it inside is not doing it any favors. You just need to prevent it from being eaten.

This.  To be clear for the OP - Peach trees are deciduous - ie they loose their leaves over winter.  They also expect it to experience cold weather for some time (depending on variety) in order to then blossom and yield fruit.  Have a read of https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/peach/peach-chill-hours.htm
